# VSCode debug nodemon throwing error - Process picker failed (Invalid XML content.)

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

When I try to debug vscode nodeapi, I am getting this error.

[image]

My launch.JSON looks like this,

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [{
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Node: Nodemon",
            "processId": "${command:PickProcess}",
            "restart": true,
            "protocol": "inspector"
        }
    ]
}
```